# Weather information

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to learn making API calls to openweather.org using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. With lot difficulties wrote code but not sure what the mistake I am doing here. I have to get the output in the console of Chrome, but unable to get. Can you guys let me know where I am making mistake? Below is my code. All the 3 files .html, .css and .js are saved in a single directory.

`index.html` file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <title>Weather</title>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:0px; color:white; background-color: #4aa1f3;">
        <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size:50px; font-weight:600;"> Get current weather</h2>

    </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                <h3 class="text-center text-primary">Enter City Name</h3>
                <span id="error"></span>

            </div>
            <div class="row form-group form-inline" id="rowDiv">
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City Name">
                <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-primary">Search City</button>          
            </div>
            <div id="show">     </div>

        </div>

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="weatherr.js"></script>



        </body>
    </html>
```

`style.css` file

```
 #rowDiv{
        margin:auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    input[type="text"]{
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;

    }
    #submitWeather{
        height:40px;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

`weather.js` file

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitweather').click(function(){
            var city = $("#city").val();
            if(city != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=c49f2a5b07ce03250befb407c4410be3",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(data){

                  console.log(data);



                    }
                });

            } else {
                $("#error").html('field cannot be empty');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(data){

   console.log(data);

}
```

You should put your code to display the data where you want here. The way you put it, it will only show in the `console`.

I think you meant something along the lines:

```
$("#show").html(data);
```

Use the `console.log(data)` to see what `data` is returning.

I hope it helps you!

**You missed an uppercase letter:**

```
$("#submitWeather").click(...)
```

not `$('#submitweather').click(..)`

Comment: i want to put the output in chrome console to test.. it is not showing anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is Display the Data that the Weather API is sending back to you. Now let's look at what the data looks like:
[Wether for NY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tObDc.jpg)
This is the current weather forecast for New York. 
You see that the Information you want is in the `weather` Array.
To access that you need to change your Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitWeather').click(function(){
        var city = $("#city").val();
        if(city != ''){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=c49f2a5b07ce03250befb407c4410be3",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data){

              // you gave the DIV that you want to display the weather information in "show", so that's where this is going:
                var html = "<h2>"+data.name+"</h2><br>";
                data.weather.forEach(function(city) {
                    html += "\n"+"<p><img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+city.icon+".png'>"+city.description+"</p>";
                });

                $("#show").html(html);                  

                }
            });

        } else {
            $("#error").html('field cannot be empty');
        }
    });
});
```

You can do a lot more with the Data, but with this, it is working like a charm.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submitWeather').click(function() {
    var city = $("#city").val();
    if (city != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID=c49f2a5b07ce03250befb407c4410be3",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {

          // you gave the DIV that you want to display the weather information in "show", so that's where this is going:
          var html = "<h2>" + data.name + "</h2><br>";
          data.weather.forEach(function(city) {
            html += "\n" + "<p><img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + city.icon + ".png'>" + city.description + "</p>"
          });

          $("#show").html(html);

        }
      });

    } else {
      $("#error").html('field cannot be empty');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#rowDiv {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#submitWeather {
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Weather</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-bottom:0px; color:white; background-color: #4aa1f3;">
    <h2 class="text-center" style="font-size:50px; font-weight:600;"> Get current weather</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
      <h3 class="text-center text-primary">Enter City Name</h3>
      <span id="error"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="row form-group form-inline" id="rowDiv">
      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City Name">
      <button id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-primary">Search City</button>
    </div>
    <div id="show"> </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="weather.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```